# How to tell mocha where to find my tests recursively?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I have the following folder structure:

- app

  - lambda

    - users

      - handler.js
    - companies

      - handler.js
- tests

  - mocha.opts
  - package.lock.json
  - package.json
  - lambda

    - users

      - handler.test.js
      - helper.js
    - companies

      - handler.test.js
      - fixture.js

When I run the 'npm test' from the following location

C:\myproject\tests> npm test

I get the following warning because it cannot find the tests to be run.

*Warning: Could not find any test files matching pattern: test

No test files found

npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.*

**How can I configure it to tell Mocha to run only all my 'handler.test.js' files?**

I have this on my package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "mocha './lambda/**/*.test.js'"}
```

I would expect that to work, but it is not finding the tests files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I configure it to tell Mocha to run only all my
>   'handler.test.js' files?

Try this:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "mocha tests/lambda/**/*.test.js --recursive"
}
```

Comment: I am not using nodemon. And 'mocha --recursive' will not work for me. Thanks

Comment: You were under something. The following works for me: "mocha ./lambda/**/*.test.js --recursive"